# Run Java Applets on Android

Tags: java, android, applet

I'm wondering if it would be possible to run Java applets on Android? It would be most convenient if I could test a few things on the go, when I only have my tablet with me. I have tried AIDE and it doesn't seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: If I have answered your question, feel free to mark it as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can't run Java applet on Android, but you can easily convert from Java applet to Android app. You just need to change front-end layer from swing to Android and maybe some listeners.

You can't use Swing or Awt on Android.